# How to replace specific values in a dataset with randomized numbers?

Tags: r, if-statement, sample, dplyr

I have a data column that contains a bunch of ranges as strings (e.g. "2 to 4", "5 to 6", "7 to 8" etc.). I'm trying to create a new column that converts each of these values to a random number within the given range. How can I leverage conditional logic within my function to solve this problem?

I think the function should be something along the lines of:

```
df<-mutate(df, c2=ifelse(df$c=="2 to 4", sample(2:4, 1, replace=TRUE), "NA"))
```

Which should produce a new column in my dataset that replaces all the values of "2 to 4" with a random integer between 2 and 4, however, this is not working and replacing every value with "NA".

Ideally, I am trying to do something where the dataset:

```
df<-c("2 to 4","2 to 4","5 to 6")
```

Would add a new column:

```
df<-c2("3","2","5")
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the string on `"to"` and create a range between the two numbers after converting them to numeric and then use `sample` to select any one of the number in range.

```
df$c2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$c1, "\\s+to\\s+"), function(x) {
         vals <- as.integer(x)
         sample(vals[1]:vals[2], 1)
})

df
#      c1 c2
#1 2 to 4  2
#2 2 to 4  3
#3 5 to 6  5
```

**data**

```
df<- data.frame(c1 = c("2 to 4","2 to 4","5 to 6"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: A silly improvement: replace `as.numeric` with `as.integer`.

Comment: @lmo Done.  Just out of curiosity, how do both differ? Does any one have advantage over the other? except that one expects integer to be returned and other numeric ?

Comment: It is not 100% clear in this case, but `as.integer` creates a vector that is 50% the size of as.numeric. A further benefit in this case, and probably the primary one, is that `sample` and `:` expect integer arguments. The `as.integer` removes the need for a copy. Again, not super important in this case, but can be important in working with large datasets.

Comment: Although, I did have to add `unlist()` and `as.character()` to get it to work in practice:



 `vals<-as.integer(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\s+to\\s+")))`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with `sub`.  Replace the `to` with `:` and `eval`uate to get the sequence, then get the `sample` of 1 from it

```
df$c2 <- sapply(sub(" to ", ":", df$c1), function(x) 
                sample(eval(parse(text = x)), 1))
df
#      c1 c2
#1 2 to 4  4
#2 2 to 4  3
#3 5 to 6  5
```

---

Or with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(gsubfn("(\\d+) to (\\d+)", ~ sample(seq(as.numeric(x), 
        as.numeric(y), by = 1), 1), df$c1))
```

---

Or with `read.table/Map` from `base R`

```
sapply(do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, read.csv(text = sub(" to ", ",", df$c1),
         header = FALSE))), sample, 1)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c("2 to 4", "2 to 4", "5 to 6")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```